# With JDBC, how do I search postgres text for a question mark?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure, escaping

I'm using JDBC via Clojure and want to search my postgres fields for whether they literally contain a question mark, but can't seem to get anything to work regardless of how I try to escape or double up my question marks.

```
    (jdbc/query *db* "SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE full_text @@ to_tsquery('?')")
= > ()
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for query seems to say that the parameter should be a vector (like in Alan's execute samples). Is that just a copy/paste mistake?

That said - are you sure you're looking in the right spot? To me it seems your `to_tsquery('?')` is the issue here. That returns nothing.

```
select to_tsquery('?');
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored

Successfully run. Total query runtime: 73 msec.
1 rows affected.
```

This doesn't seem to be a Clojure or JDBC question, this is just postgresql. Can you describe your schema and what you want to archive in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

The trick was fairly obvious: just use a prepared statement where its ? points to a value that includes your searched-for ?.

```
(require '[honeysql.core :as sql]
(defn dbr [s] (jdbc/query *db* s))
(-> {:select [:*] :from [:conversations] :where [:like :full_text "%?%"]} sql/format dbr)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean here, but I think you misunderstand what the problem was. Adding honeysql doesn't make this a prepared statement (parameterized, yes - but you could've done that without honeysql). What sql/format spits out after accepting your map is ```["SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE (full_text like ?)" "%?%"]```. You dropped your ```to_tsquery``` completely, which was the whole problem to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck [using the `jdbc/execute!` function](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html#Deleting%20rows), as it is basically a raw SQL string passed to the DB:

```
(j/execute! db-spec
   ["update fruit set cost = ( 2 * grade ) where grade > ?" 50.0] )
```

I would leave off the parameter (at least to start), more like:

```
(j/execute! db-spec
   ["update fruit set cost = ( 2 * grade ) where grade > 50.0" ])
```

Except in your case the `?` may be interpreted as a placeholder for a param.  Maybe escaping will be required.